# Minecraft "non-violent" alternatives to get resources?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am recently playing multiplayer PS3 Minecraft with my young kid.
My child was delighted when we gathered a few cows near our house. Admittedly, those baby animals are so cute.

Now I hit a dilemma ; I was planning to slaughter a few bovine for their leather, but I do not want to hurt my young child's feelings...
Is there any efficient way to get resources such as leather in Minecraft PS3 without having to murder innocent animals?

Comment: I guess leather is obtained from animals(realistically). Hmm.. Vegetarian leather..........

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: Of course I am serious. When playing alone I love all the aspects of Minecraft, including the more "mature" ones. However one of the reasons of the game popularity is that you can focus on building things together, instead of having to endure a gameplay limited to the annihilation of other living beings - like in so many other games. This makes it more appropriate for very young gamers. The presence of the "Peaceful" mode is an evidence that this type of play is acknowledged by the developers.

Comment: Additional information: I currently want leather to craft [item frames](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Item_Frame).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Leather) from the official Minecraft Wiki, leather is typically only gained from killing Cows, Mooshrooms, Horses, and Llamas. However, a less reliable way to get Leather is to go fishing. Leather has a chance to turn up as a junk item from fishing, although it's much less reliable.

The only other option may be to find a Leatherworker villager, which will be wearing a white apron. The Wiki does not mention if you can buy leather from them, however you can sell Leather to the Leatherworker. Again, this is a much less reliable method, as you will need piles of emeralds to get the amounts you desire.

Comment: Don't forget about crafting it from Rabbit Hides.

Comment: @John Yes, I saw that, however considering the OPs request of not "killing innocent animals", I thought it best not to mention it.

Comment: Please note, additionaly, that Leatherworker villagers DON'T sell Leather to you.

Answer (score 2):

**You can fish for it. There are small chances to catch some Leather as "Junk".** Alternatively, leave the house's surroundings and get hunting some wild Cows / Rabbits / Horses.